# Any way to know the absolute path of a resource in a web site when I load it in the browser?

Tags: language-agnostic

Any way to know the absolute path of a resource (an image for example) in a web site when I load it in the browser?

For example, if an image is in /var/www/project/web/images/foo.jgp I want to get that path.

In localhost I mean.

Regards

Javier

Comment: No. Localhost is just a local webserver, it is the same as a real server. Actually, if you know what web server is running on your computer you can predict the path (for Apache on Debian `http://localhost/project/web/images/foo.jgp => /var/www/project/web/images/foo.jgp`), but in general you can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about trying to get the path for an image on a public website (where you don't have access to the web server), you're not likely to find it. Think about this for a minute. It's a **security issue**. Nobody wants the actual address on their web server to become public information. That would make it much easier for a hacker to gain access. You already know the IP address, so all you need is the drive name and root folder name, and you're in.

This doesn't take into account that the images may be stored on a different server(s), such as a CDN, which would store the images on multiple servers around the world for rapid retrieval. For larger websites these days, that would be quite common. It speeds up website performance.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way to get that information in a browser.